# How to solve the page links using .htaccess in php project

Tags: php, .htaccess

currently im working on a php project where i want to clean my URL using .htaccess and below code contains in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteRule printQuotation/(.*)/ printQuotation.php?quotation_no=$1
RewriteRule printQuotation/(.*) printQuotation.php?quotation_no=$1
RewriteRule printInvoice/(.*)/ printInvoice.php?invoice_no=$1
RewriteRule printInvoice/(.*) printInvoice.php?invoice_no=$1

ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/swift/main/404
```

its works fine, but when i want to print the invoice or quotation no in print page its return the output like:

```
<?php
$quotation_ no = $_GET["quotation_no"];
echo $quotation_no;
```

output: 1938213.php

Comment: earlier this code using for remove .php extension from all php files

Comment: please anybody help me in this issue

Comment: You should probably do this in opposite order (check for your specific printQuotation/printInvoice patterns first), and use the L flag to prevent further rewriting.

Comment: Also, don’t show “output” without saying what _input_ lead to it in the first place. Mention which URL you requested!

Comment: localhost/swift/main/printQuotation/1938213